# OS Platform support macros and boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I wrote below code to detect OS and it is working fine with boost version > 1.55 but older boost library ( e.g. 1.48 ) do not support operating system macros.

Below is the sample code that works fine with boost >= 1.55.

```
std::string GetOSPlatform()
{
    std::string platformStr = "Unknown";

     #if defined(BOOST_OS_MACOS) || defined(BOOST_OS_IOS)
         platformStr = "osx";
     #endif
     #if defined(BOOST_OS_WINDOWS)
         platformStr = "windows";
         #if BOOST_ARCH_X86_64
           platformStr += "-x64";
         #endif
     #endif
     #if defined(BOOST_OS_UNIX) || defined(BOOST_OS_LINUX)
         platformStr = "linux";
         #if BOOST_ARCH_X86_64
           platformStr += "-x64";
         #endif
     #endif
     #if BOOST_OS_SOLARIS
         platformStr = "solaris";
         #if BOOST_ARCH_SPARC
           platformStr += "-sparc";
         #else
           platformStr += "-x64";
         #endif
     #endif
     #if BOOST_OS_HPUX 
         platformStr = "hp-ux";
     #endif

     return platformStr;
}

int main()
{
    std::string pltform = GetOSPlatform();
    std::cout << "platform....." << pltform << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here "BOOST_OS_*" macros are not supported with boost version < 1.55 so how to replace above code so that it works with older boost version as well ?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you add a "c" tag? Please read the descriptions of tags before blindly applying them!

Comment: You'll have to implement roughly what the v1.55 or later macros implement for yourself.  If the older version doesn't supply them, you'll have to do so instead.  Or insist that the machines are upgraded to Boost 1.55 or later.  It's probably easier to require the upgrade.

Comment: BTW: Why do you care for a Boost version that was released five years (https://www.boost.org/users/history) ago? Also, depending on the definition of "works", which is lacking from your question, the above code actually does work! Please read [ask] and be more specific concerning your goals.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am concern about earlier version because centOS 6 provides older version with yum so i need to validate with all versions of boost.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the code to work, you add some conditional compilation based on the version of Boost that you are running. If it's 1.55 or later, you just compile the code as it is. If it's an earlier version, you simply reproduce the OS detection code that later Boost versions use locally, e.g. by simply copying the code from a later version.